# How to get notification on when richedit control has maximum text length

Tags: mfc, richedit

I want to increment the height of my edit control when size of string in richedit control gets maximum means to its width. I have used EN_MaxText but it is not working in RichEdit control.

Comment: How isn't it working?  Is it not sending the message?  How do you attempt to intercept the message?

Comment: I have created control notofication handler for EN_MAXTEXT, that is OnEnMaxtext(). But it never gets executed.

Comment: Do you want to check if the max character count is reached or if the text fits into the control without scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnChange event and check the length. If it is reached you can do whatever you want, like use a MessageBox notifying the user.